# How do I turn off Wii remote sounds?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

Once in a while I play games with headphones on to avoid disturbing others around me. This works well except with the Wii when games play certain sounds through the Wii remote controllers rather than through my TV's speakers.

Is there a way to turn those sounds off? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After pressing the Home button on the Wii Remote, click on the `Wii Remote Settings` option at the bottom of the screen. You'll be presented with a volume setting for the Wii Remote's internal speaker.

Comment: I have the same problem, and yes we tried the home ,remote settings and no it has no affect. Is theis a common problem? My three other remotes do the same thing.